# asp.net mvc don't use EntityState.Modified update row

Tags: entity-framework

I have the below to multiply two input values which makes a third value row.
I also check on create to verify the name in the inventory isn't the same. If it is I would like to UPDATE instead of INSERT, how do Update without using `EntityState.Modified` ? Is there a similiar code to the add function I have below so that I can update instead of insert? I only need the syntax like below.

```
 db.inventory.Add(new inventory
{
inventory_name = inventory.name,
inventory_cost = inventory.cost,
inventory_total_amount = inventory.total_amount,
inventory_total_cost = inventory.total_amount * inventory_cost
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution was to do the following:

```
 var update = (from p in db.inventory 
               where p.name.ToLower() == POSTDATA.name.ToLower() 
               select p).FirstOrDefault();

 update.cost = update.cost + POSTDATA.cost;
 update.total_amount= update.total_amount+ POSTDATA.total_amount;
 update.total_cost= update.total_amount * update.cost
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I was able to edit the rows I chose specifficlly and do my math to automatically add the data needed.